# How do I manipulate browser's URL and back button on an "inbox-like-Gmail" application

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How AJAX is done in github source browse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9041872/how-ajax-is-done-in-github-source-browse)

I have an application that basically have 2 main pages:

1. Main page with a list of applications (like an inbox list)
2. A single application page with lot's of things to do there (like a single message)

**I have 2 concerns that I don't understand how to solve:**

1. **The browser's URL** : on the first page it will be `www.foobar.com/inbox` and on the second page it will be `www.foobar.com/inbox?app=1234`. How do I do it without really going to another page or refreshing the page
2. **the browser back/forward button** - how do I manipulate them so if I am on a single page and I push "back" I go back to inbox and not to the previous page? I read some discussions about it and couldn't understand where to start from.

Answer (score 0):

Look at gmail url and you will see `#` (hash), like:

```
document.location.hash;
```

There are many plugins, you can start from here:

[Ben Alman - jQuery hashchange event](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-hashchange/examples/hashchange/#test1)

Comment: This is not a good approach to the problem and [introduces problems of its own](http://isolani.co.uk/blog/javascript/BreakingTheWebWithHashBangs), so many that [Twitter stopped using them](http://engineering.twitter.com/2012/05/improving-performance-on-twittercom.html).

Comment: @Quentin Thanks, I just answer question how it works. I think, he will make choice himself.