# Hash tag, query string, and Ajaxified search results

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have a search form that automatically sends POST data my web application whenever something in the form changes. The web application (written in PHP/CodeIgniter) accepts POST or GET and returns the proper results and displays it on the page. Everything works fine.

Now, my concern is that the URL does not reflect the query parameters needed to get the current search results. So, if someone copied the address and shared it, the people clicking on that URL won't see the intended data. Same problem with book marking, etc.

It's possible to update the query string in jQuery, but that forces the browser to redirect to the new URL (which when it does, the page shows the correct search results because the web application was actually originally written to work non-JS). That redirecting means the Ajaxifying efforts were wasted.

Seems like hash # can be used to update the address without making the browser redirect, but I can't seem to use that information in non-JS situation (I can't access that info via GET).

What approach should I be using for this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How AJAX is done in github source browse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9041872/how-ajax-is-done-in-github-source-browse)

Answer (score 2):

HTML5 browsers support [History pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) which can update the browser's url without refreshing the page.

```
var stateObj = { foo: "bar" };
history.pushState(stateObj, "page 2", "bar.html");
```

You can add support for browsers that do not support it with [history.js](https://github.com/balupton/History.js/)

Comment: And what happens for non-HTML5 browsers?

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie — Let them fall back to the non-Ajax version.

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie you could add a link to your page with the current search and tell your visitors to copy that instead of the url in the bar

Comment: history.js changes the URL using hash, right? Or if it can change the query string, it redirects right?

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie I hadn't looked at `history.js` before, but it looks like it uses `pushState` where applicable and then falls-back to `hashchange`.

Comment: If it falls back to `hashchange`, then that becomes useless to me. I think. Right?

Comment: No you add code into the page to handle it.It will take some effort. Plus you will have to handle the back and forward actions in the browser anyway.

Comment: In a year's time no-one will be using `history.js`. Using it now just means re-writing in a year. Follow @Quentin 's advice and let non-`pushState` browsers fall back to the non-Ajax version.

Comment: @SeanHogan You really see IE8 and IE9 not being supported in a year? Can I have some of that KoolAid?

Comment: @epascarello The KoolAid is free. Help yourself. =)