# Refresh content without refreshing page and with nice url's (no hashtags # - no question marks ?)

Tags: php, html, ajax

I have the classic problem of having a website where i want to keep the header and menu divs always the same and then having the conent div changing upon user input over the menu.

This i did with php include, its nice, but of course the whole page refreshes every time the content div changes. This would be fine because refreshing the whole page is very quick... except for the logo! So i would like that just the header stays without refreshing (the logo stays nicely and static).

One solution is to only refresh the content div using Ajax, i know, but then as far as i know (and especially if you want your content indexable), you get hashtags in your url, plus getting indexed by search engines is kind of complicated ([see here](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started))

I found some websites that seem to "freeze" the menu while the rest of the page changes, and the urls are totally like basic html. For example http://www.dfab.arch.ethz.ch/ Notice how the left hand white rectangle area doesnt refresh while clicking on the other one´s menu, and the simple urls. Any idea how this is done? 
Thank you.

Comment: "i know, but then you get hashtags in your url" citation needed

Comment: in the same link provided for google´s explanation on how to set url's so that they can be indexed: `www.example.com/ajax.html#!key=value` They even suggest adding a "!" so that google knows that the site is crwaler friendly

Comment: I have edited the question though, is it better now?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How AJAX is done in github source browse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9041872/how-ajax-is-done-in-github-source-browse)

Comment: @fartagaintuxedo — #! is a dirty hack that standards have obsoleted

Comment: @Quentin -- perhaps, though i suspect that the website i show as example is not using Ajax nor pushState at all, is this possible or im i getting it totally wrong?

Comment: In that particular case, the left hand side *does* reload. It is just that the pages are sufficiently light weight, and that they are quite short so you rarely scroll, that it isn't very noticeable.

Comment: Using ob buffer seems to prevent (visual) flickering of websites as well. Well in my opinion though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what I can understand the website you mention: http://www.dfab.arch.ethz.ch/ does not use any kind of asynchrony. It is using a plain javascript to preload the big background images, which doesn't assess your problem:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--
   function BilderVorladen() {
    document.Vorladen = new Array();
    if(document.images) {
        for(var i = 0; i < BilderVorladen.arguments.length; i++) {
            document.Vorladen[i] = new Image();
            document.Vorladen[i].src = BilderVorladen.arguments[i];
        }
    }
}
//-->
</script>
```

Possible solutions for your original issue are: HTML iframes (somewhat ugly and [discouraged by google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/81766?hl=en&ref_topic=2370420)) or if you want to keep the asynchronous approach without the ajax hacks, your solution is definitely [websockets](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/) (see [here](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills#web-sockets) for IE polyfills), but that won't ease the SEO as well.

Honestly they all looks like overkills for a slow loading logo. I would rather change approach and reduce the img size and/or format and make sure the img gets cached, so that it has to be downloaded just the first time (usually a very acceptable delay).

Comment: So the images show up that quickly because they are cached.. didnt think of that, thanks!