# Why use an 'at' (@) sign in a url instead of 'hash' (#)

Tags: javascript, html, url, hashtag

Google maps is changing the url with an 'at' `@` (not `%40`) instead of the 'hash' `#` without a page reload. All the newest browsers are supporting it.
I haven't see this before and I couldn't find any information on this topic (probably because 'at' is a common word).

1. What is the browser support for the `@ sign?
2. Why use an `@` instead of `#`?
3. Is there a default Javascript/JQuery function like `window.location.hash`?

**Example:**

https://www.google.nl/maps/@52.4989114,5.2799319,11z

When you move the map around the url will changes without a reload.

Comment: @ unlike # is part of url which the server receives (# in purely client-side).

Comment: So is the hash officially called a hashtag now? Nobody seems to call it a hash anymore.

Comment: Changing the url "without reloading" is called a "push". You have access to the API through `window.history.pushState()`. I guess `@` is just a prefix Google uses for long/lat detection for reason mentioned by @Cthulhu.

Comment: That has nothing to do with HTTP protocol in this case. I guess @ `is included as a variable. And then they check if a variable contains `@` then respond via JSON, otherwise send a content of some page

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19509028/at-symbol-inside-urls

Comment: A hashtag is a means of indicating that a term should be hyperlinked to a search engine on social media networks. It gets the name because it it uses a hash character to prefix it. Please don’t confuse other uses of the hash character with hashtags.

Comment: In my mind `#` mostly resembles a [tic-tac-toe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tic-tac-toe) grid. It's a shame we don't call them tic-tac-toe-tags.

Comment: The whimsical Google engineers likely just use "@" as a notation for *"at location ..."*, which is exactly what that parameter is. It means nothing special beyond that to browsers.

Comment: @deceze: Google, what are you doing? "@" clearly means "at a person", everyone knows that!

Comment: Let's meet @BoltClock later!

Comment: @BoltClock I'm just glad, people stopped calling it 'pound'.

Comment: And let's #BoltClock later too. @musaul

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. It's fine
2. So it gets sent to the server
3. No

> When you move the map around the url will changes without a reload.

They use [pushState and friends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9041872/how-ajax-is-done-in-github-source-browse). The `@` has no special significance (beyond what Google gives it on their servers) here.

Answer (score 1):

They use HTML5 session history and navigation API.

With [`pushState`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110113/history.html#dom-history-pushstate) you can set the URL without refresh the page.

You can see examples: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history